# Use SELECT AVG with parameters "SELECT AVG(@parameter)" SQL!

Tags: sql, select, parameters, average

I'm working with a table of float values, but I enter the column by parameter

SELECT AVG(@var) AS Aver
FROM ListVal

When I enter the column name (the parameter) I recieve an error: That the datatype nvarchar is not valid for the avg operator. But all the columns are float.

Help!!! please

Comment: using exclamation marks (outside of code blocks) is kind of impolite

Answer (score 4):

You have to use dynamic SQL

e.g.

```
EXEC( 'SELECT AVG( [' + @var + '] ) AS Aver FROM ListVal' )
```

Answer (score 2):

Query parameters substitute for a single literal value, not a column name.  This is standard SQL behavior, supported the same in every brand of RDBMS.

So you supplied the name of a column and it's as if you ran this query:

```
SELECT AVG('columnname') ...
```

Which is a meaningless operation.  What's the `AVG()` of a string?

@Matt Rogish is correct in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472651/use-select-avg-with-parameters-select-avgparameter-sql/1472680#1472680) that the only way to make column names (or table names, or other SQL syntax) dynamic is to use dynamic SQL.  That is, interpolate application variables into a string, and then use the resulting string as an SQL query.

You can use query parameters only to inject a single scalar value, and that's how the parameter will be interpreted in the query.